# iOS load resources from a bundle

Tags: bundle, ios6

I've just a little problem with Xcode. From an existing project I've derived a static library (with source code) and a *.bundle (inside there's only a storyboard and images used in the storyboard). In the second project, I've linked the library (it works properly) and the bundle (in the copy bundle resources of build phases there's the *.bundle). When I try to load the storyboard, it loads it but without the images.
There's the code where I call the storyboard:

```
UIStoryboard *story=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"MYCOMPANY.BUNDLE1"]];

MyViewController *libViewContr= [story instantiateInitialViewController];

libViewContr.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;                
[self presentViewController:libViewContr animated:YES completion:nil ];
```

Thank you to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. I found out the png assets are compressed to .tiff format while building the bundle. you can disable this by setting 'Combine High Resolution Artwork' in the target settings to FALSE/NO.